# PHP Jquery Calendar Widget

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

OK, this sounds simple and or like something that should have probably been done a million times but i cant find an example.

I need to put a small calendar widget on a page that highlights dates if matching a date field from mysql. If user clicks this date go to a page and pass a variable like the date clicked?

Im sure this should be able to be done with jquery (datepicker maybe) and php fairly easy but im stumpped?

Any direction would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/) from YUI Library